# Error while creating services using Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

Well I am developing a rest service. 
It has the following controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/userFoodObservation")
public class UserFoodObservationController extends CommonController{

QSenseLogger logger = QSenseLogger.getLogger(getClass());

@Autowired
private UserFoodObservationService userFoodObservationService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/logFood", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object createUserFoodObservation(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody UserFoodObservationBlockTO foodObservationBlockTO) throws Exception{
    ResponseTO responseTO = new ResponseTO();
    responseTO.setSuccess(false);
    try{
        Long userId = Long.parseLong(request.getHeader("userId"));
        String timezoneId = request.getHeader("timezoneId");            
        boolean returnResult = userFoodObservationService.createUserFoodObservation(userId, timezoneId, foodObservationBlockTO);
        if(returnResult){
            responseTO.setSuccess(true);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("ConstraintViolationException in userFoodObservationBlock Table".toLowerCase())){
            logger.info("Unable to create food Observations because this block had already been synced", e.getMessage());
            responseTO.setSuccess(true);
        }
        else{
            logger.error("Error occured while creating food observation ");         
        }
    }
    return responseTO;
}
}
```

And this is the UserFoodObservationBlockTO  DTO

```
public class UserFoodObservationBlockTO implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -657264742567486410L;

    private Long sessionId; 

    private List<UserFoodObservationTO> foodObservations;

    public Long getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    public void setSessionId(Long sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public List<UserFoodObservationTO> getFoodObservations() {
        return foodObservations;
    }

    public void setFoodObservations(List<UserFoodObservationTO> foodObservations) {
        this.foodObservations = foodObservations;
    }



}
```

And then we have a food observation DTO as

```
public class UserFoodObservationTO implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4264600862718416440L;

    private Long foodSubTypeId; 

    private String time;

    private int food_serving_size;

    private Long sessionId;

    private Long sessionRecordId;

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getFood_serving_size() {
        return food_serving_size;
    }

    public void setFood_serving_size(int food_serving_size) {
        this.food_serving_size = food_serving_size;
    }

    public Long getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    public void setSessionId(Long sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public Long getSessionRecordId() {
        return sessionRecordId;
    }

    public void setSessionRecordId(Long sessionRecordId) {
        this.sessionRecordId = sessionRecordId;
    }

    public Long getFoodSubTypeId() {
        return foodSubTypeId;
    }

    public void setFoodSubTypeId(Long foodSubTypeId) {
        this.foodSubTypeId = foodSubTypeId;
    }



}
```

But when I'm calling the rest service through postman with Params

```
{
   "sessionId": "2",
   "foodObservations": [
       {
       "foodSubType": "1",
       "time": "2016-12-15 09:00:00",
       "food_serving_size": "3",
       "sessionId": "2",
       "sessionRecordId": "1"

       }
   ]
}
```

It says The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. 
if anyone could help me about it. It would be really appreciated.

Comment: Turn up logging to DEBUG, and you should get more specific information. I will note that you have both `foodSubType` and `foodSubTypeId`, which might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following JSON:

```
{
   "sessionId": "2",
   "foodObservations": [
       {
       "foodSubTypeId": "1",
       "time": "2016-12-15 09:00:00",
       "food_serving_size": "3",
       "sessionId": "2",
       "sessionRecordId": "1"

       }
   ]
}
```

The reason might be that Spring can't parse Your JSON into expected class object because the field name differ.